# remove line breaks and spaces around span elements with python regex

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

After using BeautifulSoup's prettify, I want to remove the line breaks and indentation from around `span` and maybe other inline tags.

For example, I currently have something like this:

```
>>> import bs4
>>> html = "<div><p>I don't want this <span>span element</span> on it's one line.</p></div>"
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
>>> soup.prettify()
"<div>\n <p>\n  I don't want this\n  <span>\n   span element\n  </span>\n  on its one line.\n </p>\n</div>"
>>> print(soup.prettify())
<div>
 <p>
  I don't want this
  <span>
   span element
  </span>
  on it's one line.
 </p>
</div>
```

What regex can I use to remove the indentation spaces and newlines around the span tags so that I end up with this:

```
<div>
 <p>
  I don't want this <span>span element</span> on its one line.
 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not great, but you can do `soup.prettify().replace("\n  <span>\n   ", " <span>").replace("\n  </span>\n ", "</span>")` if it always appears that way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [customize BeautifulSoup's prettify by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583415/customize-beautifulsoups-prettify-by-tag)

Comment: the duplicate suggestion still puts the span on its own line.  Thanks for the suggestions though.  I'm trying to modify it to get the results I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is quite old, and Mohamed already provided a stellar answer. However, I wanted to add to it.

While this works great, I found it missed tags which had a newline either before or after the tag (but not both). I think this is due to the '`+`' char in `[ \n]+`, which is saying to match one or more `\n` or space (so if the tag doesn't have one ore more space or newline chars both before and after it, it won't match). I used his approach, but switched it to the following:

```
# removing space before and after <span> tag
html = re.sub('\s*<span>\s*','<span>', html)

# removing space before and after </span> tag
html = re.sub('\s*</span>\s*','</span>', html)
```

`\s` will match any whitespace character (space, tab, new line, etc.), and the `*` says to match 0 or more of these (so if there's a whitespace character only on one side of the tag, it will still match)

Additionally, if any of your  elements have attributes (i.e. `<span class="myclass">`), you will need to do something extra as well:

```
'''
[^>]* says match 0 or more of any characters OTHER than >,
so you'd match: <span>, <span class="a">, <span style="display:hidden;">, etc...)
(the parens around it, store it in a capture class,
so it can be inserted in the replacement.)
'''
tag_regex = re.compile('\s*<span([^>]*)>\s*')
'''
the \1 inserts what was captured by the regex
(the [^>*], our attributes, if any) in to the replacement text. 
''' 
html = tag_regex.sub('<span\\1>', html)

# removing space before and after </span> tag
html = re.sub('\s*</span>\s*','</span>', html)
```

Putting this all together in Mohamed's general function that works for any tag, we get:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def prettify_output(html, tag):
    reg_tag = re.compile(f'\s*<{tag}([^>]*)>\s*')
    html = reg_tag.sub(f'<{tag}\\1>', html)
    html = re.sub(f'\s*</{tag}>\s*',f'</{tag}>', html)
    return html

html = BeautifulSoup("<body><div><div><span class='a'>dont</span><span class='b'>split me!</span></div></div></body>", 'html.parser')
html = html.prettify() # or however you call BeautifulSoup's prettify
html = prettify_output(html, 'span')
```

Produces the output:

```
<body>
 <div>
  <div><span class="a">dont</span><span class="b">split me!</span></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

An improvement would be to preserve the newline before `<span *stuff*>` and after `</span>`, unless they are nested between/beside other spans (this would keep the prettified newline between `<div>` and `<span class="a">`, as well as between that `</span>` and `</div>` tag - currently the function takes those away, as it's removing all whitespace characters before and after those tags.)

Answer (score 2):

check this out :

```
import re

html = '''
    <div>
        <p>
            I don't want this
            <span>
                span element
            </span>
            on it's one line.
        </p>
    </div>
'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)

## getting prettified output 
html = soup.prettify()


# removing \n and space before and after <span> tag
html = re.sub('[ \n]+<span>[ \n]+','<span>', html)

# removing \n and space before and after </span> tag
html = re.sub('[ \n]+</span>[ \n]+','</span>', html)
```

doing `print(html)` gives you the following output :

```
<div>
   <p>
       I don't want this<span>span element</span>on it's one line.
   </p>
</div>
```

you can create a function that does this for different tags:

```
import re

def prettify_output(html, tag):
    html = re.sub(f'[ \n]+<{tag}>[ \n]+',f'<{tag}>', html)
    html = re.sub(f'[ \n]+</{tag}>[ \n]+',f'</{tag}>', html)
    return html

## call 
html = prettify_output(html, 'span')
```