# BS4: How to edit the content of a <pre> that contains <>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some HTML that contains a `pre` tag:

```
<p>Hi!</p><pre><p>Hi!</p></pre>
```

I'd like to change it to:

```
<p>Hi!</p><pre><p>Bye!</p></pre>
```

The naïve thing to do seems to be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

markup = """<p>Hi!</p><pre><p>Hi!</p></pre>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")
pre_tag = soup.pre
pre_tag.string = "<p>bye!</p>"
print(str(soup))
```

but that gives `<p>Hi!</p><pre>&lt;p&gt;bye!&lt;/p&gt;</pre>`

In the [BS4 docs there's a section on output formatters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters) that gives an example of using cdata:

```
from bs4.element import CData
soup = BeautifulSoup("<a></a>", 'html.parser')
soup.a.string = CData("one < three")
print(soup.a.prettify(formatter="html"))
# <a>
#  <![CDATA[one < three]]>
# </a>
```

Which looks like what's needed, except that it also wraps the unformatted characters in a cdata tag; not good inside a `pre`.

This question: [Beautiful Soup replaces < with <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040260/beautiful-soup-replaces-with-lt) looks like it's going in this vague direction, but isn't about the insides of a `pre` tag.

This question: [customize BeautifulSoup's prettify by tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583415/customize-beautifulsoups-prettify-by-tag) seems like overkill, and is also from the BS3 era.

p.s. the example above is indicative of wanting to do all kinds of things to the contents of a pre, not just change *hi* to *bye*. (before anyone asks)

Comment: Following up on your comment on my answer: is the output going to be displayed in a browser? You want to display the {intact, broken} HTML markup in a browser? If that's what you want, representing `<` by `&lt;` etc. seems to be the correct way to go. Otherwise, the browser would interpret+render the tag markup instead of displaying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you can use the API to construct the new contents:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

markup = """<p>Hi!</p><pre><p>Hi!</p></pre>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")
pre_tag = soup.pre

new_tag = soup.new_tag("p")
new_tag.append("bye!")

pre_tag.clear()
pre_tag.append(new_tag)

print(str(soup))
```

Or you can provide the HTML to another BeautifulSoup instance and use that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

markup = """<p>Hi!</p><pre><p>Hi!</p></pre>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(markup, "html.parser")
pre_tag = soup.pre

soup2 = BeautifulSoup("<p>bye!</p>", "html.parser")

pre_tag.clear()
pre_tag.append(soup2)

print(str(soup))
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you have any suggestions about how to handle malformed content that won't parse? E.g. demonstrating what broken HTML looks like